# how to write a method with delegate parameter in C# / .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I've been using the way that I declare delegate in class level:

```
protected delegate void FieldsDelegate();

//and then write a method e.g.

protected int CreateComponent(DbConnection cnctn, string tableName, Dictionary<string, object> changedFieldValues, FieldsDelegate fieldsDelegate)
```

However this is really cumbersome and I can't see instantly what the delegate is like. So I would like to do it like this:

```
protected int CreateComponent(DbConnection cnctn, string tableName, Dictionary<string, object> changedFieldValues, delegate void fieldsDelegate())
```

so that I don't have the separate definition.

The above is not allowed for some reason. So how can I do it?

Comment: Actually the suffix `Delegate` in `FieldsDelegate` is a very good indicator already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET now provides the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) generics for this purpose.

In your case, this delegate takes no parameters and returns nothing.

```
// protected delegate void FieldsDelegate(); // Don't need this anymore

protected int CreateComponent(
                               DbConnection cnctn, 
                               string tableName, 
                               Dictionary<string, object> changedFieldValues, 
                               Action fieldsDelegate
                            )
```

If it took a string as a parameter:

```
// protected delegate void FieldsDelegate(string s); 

protected int CreateComponent(
                               DbConnection cnctn, 
                               string tableName, 
                               Dictionary<string, object> changedFieldValues,
                               Action<string> fieldsDelegate
                             )
```

If it took a string as a parameter and returned a bool:

```
// protected delegate bool FieldsDelegate(string s); 

protected int CreateComponent(
                               DbConnection cnctn, 
                               string tableName, 
                               Dictionary<string, object> changedFieldValues,
                               Func<string, bool> fieldsDelegate
                             )
```

Comment: @Henk - I agree. It's easier to understand if I include the delegate it replaced.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the generic `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` and their variants as delegates, and the bonus is you don't even need to define a separate delegate at all.

`Action<T>` takes up to 16 different type parameters, so: `Action<T1, T2>` and on up; Each type parameter is the type parameter for the method in the same position. So, `Action<int, string>` would work for this method:

```
public void MyMethod(int number, string info)
```

`Func<T>` is the same, except it is for methods that return a value. The last type argument is the return type. `Func<T>` is not what you would use in your case here.

Example: `Func<string, int, object>` would be for a method such as:

```
public object MyOtherMethod(string message, int number)
```

Using these generic delegates makes it clear what the arguments for that delegate argument would be, which seems to be your intent.

```
public void MyMethod(Action<string, MyClass>, string message)
```

Calling that method, you know you need to pass a method in that takes a `string` and a `MyClass`.

```
public void MeOtherMethod(Func<int, MyOtherClass>, int iterations)
```

Here, you know you need to pass a method that takes an `int` parameter, and returns `MyOtherClass`